# what does private Set<String> uniqueAuthors indicate in a java snippet?

Tags: java, string, code-snippets

what does `private Set<String> uniqueAuthors;` indicate in a java snippet?

Comment: that there is a Set variable named uniqueAuthors whose scope is limited to such class that holds only String

Comment: <String> is not visible here in the question. Don't know why.

Comment: @GilbertoGaxiola Thanks. What is <String> in this code?

Comment: `<String>` looks like a HTML tag which your browser ignores because it doesn't recognise it. :P Its the type of elements allowed in the Set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It inidcates the there is `Set` which accepts only `Strings` named as `uniqueAuthors`

This is [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) syntax introduced in Java 5

Comment: +1 ... the Strings are unique and the set may or may not be replaced in the code.